# I lost my Indian passport that had my F1 visa. Can I get it reissued in Canada?

Tags: f1-visas, lost-documents

I was travelling and my passport was stolen. I received a new passport and I'm wondering if I can get my F1 stamped in Canada, as I have to travel to Canada. Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can apply in Canada. Make sure you have every document available including police report of the theft etc. Applications in third countries have lower chances of success, just FYI